# Почему мой код с использованием Moor во Flutter не работает?

Tags: flutter, dart

Всем привет. Такая проблема с Flutter при использовании библиотеки Moor. Вот код:

```
import 'package:moor_flutter/moor_flutter.dart';

@DataClassName('Todo')
class Todos extends Table {
  IntColumn get id => integer().autoIncrement()();
  TextColumn get task => text().withLength(min: 1, max: 50)();
  BoolColumn get completed => boolean().withDefault(Constant(false))();
}

@UseMoor(tables: [Todos])
class MyDatabase extends _$MyDatabase {
  MyDatabase(QueryExecutor e) : super(_openConnection(e));

  @override
  int get schemaVersion => 1;
}

LazyDatabase _openConnection(QueryExecutor e) {
  return LazyDatabase(() async {
    return await e.openDatabase('todos.db');
  });
}
```

Почему у меня подчеркивается красным extends _$MyDatabase, super(_openConnection(e)), и return await e.openDatabase('todos.db') в функции LazyDatabase. Я что только не пробовал, чтобы устранить проблему. В чем причина?